# Non-destructive beveling by different amounts on different edges?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, bevel

I'm new to Blender and have struck a brick wall, and would greatly appreciate it if any one of you can help me assess what's going on here.

I'm trying to reproduce what I created using SketchUp, but the object just won't bevel.

[image: SketchUp_model]
[image: SketchUp_modelCloseUp]
[image: Blender_model]

I would like to bevel the outer corners by X while beveling all other edges by X/2, as can be seen in the SketchUp model, all in a non-destructive manner which allows me to alter the number of segments later.

Any clue as to how I can do this?

Comment: Create Vertex Groups for more control on the vertices.

Comment: The modifier is nondestructive because it can be removed and has the segments option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create different bevels non-destructively. Like this one

[image: goal]

1. Create a bevel modifier with vertex group

[image: bevel modifier panel]

2. Assign the vertices. *make sure you add middle loop cuts before doing this so it does not affect the whole face.*

[image: bevel modifier panel with weights][image: result]

3.Add another bevel modifier. This time with weight as a limit method. 
[image]

4.Add bevel weights to the edges.

[image: additional modifier][image: result again]

Tips:

1. Bevelr does the vertex group bevel quickly. Big thanks to penfinity.https://gumroad.com/penfinity
2. If the bevels are not working properly try: apply scale, disable clamp overlap in the bevel modifier, re-arrange the modifiers.
3. The vertex group limit method can be used multiple times with different modifiers unlike the bevel weight limit method.

Comment: You don't need two bevel modifiers or vertex groups, just assign a different bevel weight to each edge.

Comment: Thanks a million! This did the trick. I opted for two vertex groups as limit methods instead of just one in combination with weight, though. It seems to grant me more control.

Comment: Glad to help! Yeah, different bevel weight works too however, it gives more control to have two modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Blender can do this with 2 bevel modifiers.

Non destructive and you can change segments at anytime.

[image]
The image above shows the use of two different vertex groups. The color options was used.

- Use two bevel modifiers.
- Create two vertex groups.
- Each one uses a different vertex group as indicated by the gold arrows.
- There are so many options and ways to do this with the modifier.
- There is an option Vertex Group
- The above image was a cube and is beveled.

Comment: @moonboots  Please see edits